# In Chrome Extension, what event is triggered when a page asks for your location?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension.  I want to have an event triggered in response to when a web page asks for a user location.

What is this event called in the Chrome API?

I can't find documentation on this specifically.  If anybody can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: There is no dedicated Chrome API. You can probably spoof/intercept the corresponding DOM API by inserting code in script element in the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I was looking through the resource at [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

It appears there's some kind of API that your background script in your extension can use.  This is my first attempt at making something specifically for Chrome and I'm not quite sure if it (1) exists, and (2) how to detect/interact with the event once it's detected.

Comment: Those API are not location-related. As for spoofing, that's not exactly trivial but you should be able to find the examples and existing extensions that do exactly the same. The underlying trick is to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)